# C - function (Assume that a and n are parameters where a is an array of int values and n is the length of the array.)

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and I don't really understand this question. Can some of you give me examples of what it means. How do I write a function where a is int values and n is the length?

I'm confused...

Comment: The function should look like this: `void foo(int a[], size_t n)` If you don't know enough C to understand the description, the probability of you completing this assignment without a lot of additional studying is very small.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: lol I don't understand how it's worded and I needed clarification. Saying the probability of me completing this assignment because of that factor is small is actually insane. I can complete it just fine now that someone has pointed out what it actually means.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is, as you haven't provided much information. However, a function in C is defined like this:

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
    body of the function
}
```

So, for this situation, we could say:

```
void arrayFunction( int a[], int n){
    //do whatever you need to do with the function here
}
```

This may help you some.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an array of ints, as follows:

```
int arr[] = {2,3,4,5,6};
```

You can see that there are 5 elements inside above array `arr`. You can count them. 
But it happens that when you pass the above `arr` to function, that function has no idea about how many elements `arr` contains. See below (incorrect) code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int arr[]){

}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {2,3,4,5,6};

    display(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The function named '`display()`' has no idea about how many elements `arr` has

Therefore you you need to pass the extra argument (the extra argument called '`n`') to tell that called function about the number of elements inside `arr`. You need to tell this separately - the length of `arr`.

Now this becomes - as you said in your question - `arr` is int values and `n` is the length

Below is the correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int a[], int n){
    //Now display knows about lenth of elemnts in array 'a'
    // Length is 5 in this case
}

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {2,3,4,5,6};
    display(arr, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, the function named '`display()`' knows the length of array of int. This is the way you write code where you specify your array and its length.

More formally, this is because while passing array, it decays to a pointer and so the need arises to pass its length also alongwith it.